# Yolo v9 saving each epoch and loss

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, google-colaboratory, yolo

Hello i `have this code to train yolov9 model on a custom dataset .. but since i only have the T4 gpu and my dataset is big , it only trained for like 3 epochs then it stops .. i wanna train each epoch by itselt and save it and it's loss .. how can i do it ??

this is the code i'm using

```
%cd /content/my_drive/MyDrive/yolov9/yolov9

!python train.py \
--batch 16 --epochs 25 --img 640 --min-items 0 --close-mosaic 15 \
--data /content/my_drive/MyDrive/yolov9/yolov9/data.yaml \
--weights /content/my_drive/MyDrive/yolov9/yolov9/gelan-c.pt \
--cfg models/detect/gelan-c.yaml \
--hyp hyp.scratch-high.yaml
```